# How often do you use DI container in your ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: dependency-injection

While reading a book, I came across DI(dependency Injector) and the subsequent DI Container tool. Previously, I developed an application following a tutorial on asp.net website which never used such tool. So, my question can be summed-up in following two concerns :-

- **How often do you use DI Container ?**
- **What requirements make you do so ?**

EDIT : Examples with and without DI Container. I have written the codes to understand which is better approach.

***Without** DI Container* --

```
LinqValueCalculator lc = new LinqValueCalculator();
ShoppingCart sc = new ShoppingCart(lc);
decimal total = sc.CalculateStockValue();
Console.WriteLine("Total: {0:c}", total);
```

***With** DI Container* -- (Ninject is used in this example)

```
IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
ninjectKernel.Bind<IValueCalculator>().To<LinqValueCalculator>();

IValueCalculator calcImpl = ninjectKernel.Get<IValueCalculator>();
ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart(calcImpl);
Console.WriteLine("Total: {0:c}", cart.CalculateStockValue());
```

I will be honest, I feel that writing first code was easier and seemed natural. But, your views are what counts as i am just learning the MVC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**How often do I use a DI Container?**

Very often. Close to always.

**What requirements make me do so?**

In ASP.NET MVC I always use a container, because when one uses Constructor Injection in Controllers one breaks the default convention of having default constructors. This means that a custom IControllerFactory is required, and while it's possible to write and maintain one by hand, it's more work. Using a DI Container that supports convention-based configuration, one can use Constructor Injection in a convention-based manner and less maintenance is required.

**Can we do without them?**

Yes, but at the cost of more maintenance of infrastructure code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667801/arguments-against-inversion-of-control-containers/5668093#5668093

Answer (score 4):

**Can we do without them?**

Yes, but you lose the ability to easily unit test your application.  Mocking the different layers/tiers of your application are much easier when you use DI.

**How often do I use them?**

Always in an MVC app.  StructureMap (for me) has made it so easy to easily set up default conventions that I really don't lose any development time for the gains that it gets me.

**BTW**, I do DI like this, using Constructor Injection (make unit testing easier):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public HomeController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_service.Method());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to write C# asp.net application with all these best practices previously.
DI is very usefull for C# language, that is out of the question. With proper design of your classes and interfaces you can make it less coupled and test / develop easier.

Year ago I switched to dynamic languages like ruby and python. My first idea was to find a DI libraries for them, but then I gave up cause I 've realized that DI is a perfect pattern for solving static language problems.